# Why does \frac not produce \mathinner atoms?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, latex-base

LaTeX defines `\frac` as

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand\frac[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}}
```

i.e. the fraction is created using `\over` surrounded by a brace group to contain its effect.
The TeXbook states on page 155

> There’s also an eighth classiﬁcation, `\mathinner`, which is not normally used for individual
> symbols; fractions and `\left...\right` constructions are treated as “inner” subformulas, which
> means that they will be surrounded by additional space in certain circumstances.

This leads me to expect that the result of `\frac{1}{2}` would be a `\mathinner` atom. However, the following MWE shows that it's not.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\(\frac{1}{2} (3 + 4 + 5)\)

\(\mathord\frac{1}{2} (3 + 4 + 5)\)

\(\mathinner\frac{1}{2} (3 + 4 + 5)\)

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

So it seems that the brace group inserted by `\frac` does *not* create a `\mathinner` atom but rather a `\mathord` one, like any other subformula.

- Seeing as `\over` needs to be enclosed in a brace group to limit its effect, when does a fraction ever create an "inner" subformula? What are the "certain circumstances" the TeXbook refers to?
- Is there any harm in prepending `\mathinner` to the definition of `\frac`, making it actually produce `\mathinner` atoms?

Comment: first bullet point a good question I thought perhaps `\overwithdelims` might work more like `\left\right` but I couldn't make an example, and I got lost reading the web code, it does use a `inner_noad` at one point (`fraction_noad: begin t:=inner_noad; s:=fraction_noad_size;`) but after that I got lost following the logic. For the second bullet point https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173740/1090

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144159/4427

Comment: there's a package that turns `\frac`s into `\mathinner`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathfixs